# Lambda function times out on bigger files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I have a Lambda function written in Python that downloads objects to the SFTP server once they get uploaded to S3. It worked perfectly with files of smaller size but I have a CSV file around 20MB which uploads to s3, sometimes it triggers lambda function, sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't trigger the Lambda function on the upload, the log stream is not created and I don't know where to start debugging. I have increased resources to 256MB and time to 60 seconds.

Is there anything else I can do?

Here is my lambda function:

```
import pysftp,os,boto3

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = os.environ.get('SFTP_HOST')
myUsername = os.environ.get('SFTP_USER')
myPassword = os.environ.get('SFTP_PASSWORD')

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the records for the triggered event
    FILEOBJ = event["Records"][0]
    BUCKET_NAME = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['bucket']['name'])
    KEY = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['object']['key'])
    FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(KEY)
    TMP_FILE_NAME = '/tmp/' +FILE_NAME

    # Download the file/s from the event (extracted above) to the tmp location
    s3.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, KEY, TMP_FILE_NAME)

    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
      with sftp.cd('user/data/uploads'):
        localFilePath = TMP_FILE_NAME
        sftp.put(localFilePath)
```

I have IAM role with 2 policies, one for S3 and another for Lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/uploads/data/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:xxxxx:xxxx:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What you're describing (the log stream is not created) suggests that the Lambda function was not actually triggered, rather than that it timed out. Double-check your S3 event configuration, where in S3 you uploaded the file to, and CloudWatch Logs for your Lambda function.

Comment: What does your Lambda triggers look like?  It sounds like you're triggering off of `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`, but not also `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`

Comment: Use `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

Comment: Exactly, why it is not triggered if I put the object into the right bucket? I checked all the configurations and everything is fine, so if I upload an object smaller in size, everything works as expected. The event type is s3:ObjectCreated:*

Comment: Are you saying that the event trigger is `s3:ObjectCreated:*` but it's not invoking the Lambda function? Seems unlikely in my experience. Almost always user error.

Comment: Can you show us your code? A common problem is that people fail to iterate through the `event['Records']` array, assuming that the function will always be called with only a single object. So, it might be that the Lambda function is invoked, but it is 'ignoring' the object being passed-in.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code and I attached policies of the IAM role that is used in this function.

Comment: Log the event. Per the earlier comment, are you sure that `len(event["Records"])` is always 1? If there happen to be 2 or more records passed to same Lambda invocation, you are dropping the 2nd and subsequent records.

Comment: that is not the issue, seems like adjusting sshd_config not to use PAM did the work, but I will keep my eye on future downloads to confirm

Comment: I don't see how that would prevent the CloudWatch Logs being written. Note that the logs can be written to an existing, reused log stream. They aren't always written to a new log stream.

Comment: well if the function wasn't actually triggered then it couldn't write any logs, it was acting like a --dry-run while it wasn't and this switch on the sftp server solved my issue.